# visual mode in vi to remove char at the end of multiple lines

Tags: vi

```
builder.append("sss");
builder.append("aaaaaaaaa");
```

I would like to remove the ; at the end. I can do it using various scripts in sed or replace all in vim.

But, I would like to know how to use visual mode.

I know how to add at the front or back
go to visual mode, j, Shift + i, add at the beginning and esc
similarly Shift + $ for the end.

But, when I tried to remove using
j, Shift + $, Shift + a, backspace and esc it doesn't work, I get the following:

```
   builder.append("sss")
   builder.append("aaaaaaaaa");)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the easiest way to do this for multiple lines is to mark the block in visual mode and then:

```
:'<,'>s/;$//
```

Note that the `'<,'>` means "from the beginning of the visual block to the end" and is added automatically when you press <kbd>:</kbd> while in visual mode.

Answer (score 0):

Place the cursor over the semicolon and use `x` to delete it.

(I assume that you're referring to vi's visual mode (as distinct from its ex mode), and not Vim's `VISUAL` mode.)

If you really want to do this with multiple lines at once, then you'll have to resort to a colon-command. If you're using Vim, then @Greg Hewgill's answer is the one for you. If you're using vi, you'll have to mark the first line with `ma` and the last with `mb`, and then process all of them with `:'a,'bs/;$//`.